# SharePoint Conference Recommendations

Tags: community, education

I hope this kind of question is allowed. I am looking ahead at Conferences for next year and wanted to get some feedback on SharePoint Conferences within the US that would be beneficial to go to.

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at: http://www.topsharepoint.com/upcoming-sharepoint-conferences

Answer (score 1):

it always depends on what exactly you'd like to learn (which topic) but it is always good to get information from the SharePoint team or MVPs.

Check [this URL](https://myignite.microsoft.com/sessions?f=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522Microsoft%2520365%2522%252C%2522facetName%2522%253A%2522products%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522SharePoint%2522%252C%2522facetName%2522%253A%2522products%2522%257D%255D) and find your session.

Hope this helps,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for the response and link. I am a SharePoint Administrator with Intermediate level knowledge of SharePoint Online, so I am pretty open to anything except on-prem server configuration and things like that. There are so many new things coming out with Office 365, so I am anxious to see the session recordings from Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hear more about SharePoint (onPrem / Cloud) then i would recommend to go for Microsoft Ignite conferee by Microsoft. You can read more about this over here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ignite/default.aspx. Ignite is must have thing.

Other than that there are many one day conferences called SharePoint Saturdays which are happening around the years across usa. You can also check the Non-Microsoft conf i.e. SharePoint fest, sharePoint conferences, Collab375 etc